# jquery filter field not working

Tags: jquery

I have number of FORMs on the screen. they are the results of query in my DB.
I added input field that should filter the results but for some reason it's not working.

Even ALERT not works...

I'll appropriate your help

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    alert (value);
    $("#agnt_list-res form").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Example for my HTML result

```
<ul class="row list-inline">
    <li><input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.."></li>
</ul>


<div id="agnt_list-res">

    <form action='#' method='post' id="4" class='fadeSec item'>

        <div class='col-md-2 item-edit' data-value='' data-type='fileArray' data-name='file[]' data-maxFiles='1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-3 item-edit' data-type='input' data-name='agnt[name]' data-require='1'>Agency 4</div>
        <div class='col-md-2 panel-menu'>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-success edit_save-btn hidden'>Save</a>
            <span class='edit_msg'></span>
        </div>

    </form> 

    <form action='#' method='post' id="5" class='fadeSec item'>

        <div class='col-md-2 item-edit' data-value='' data-type='fileArray' data-name='file[]' data-maxFiles='1'></div>
        <div class='col-md-3 item-edit' data-type='input' data-name='agnt[name]' data-require='1'>Agency 3</div>
        <div class='col-md-2 panel-menu'>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-success edit_save-btn hidden'>Save</a>
            <span class='edit_msg'></span>
        </div>

    </form> 

</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/